# Proof that $f(x) = x^TMx$ is convex

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I have been stuck on this problem for a while.

After I use the definition of convexity and some algebra, I end with something like this:

$$
\lambda f(x^{(1)}) + (1-\lambda)f(x^{(2)}) + \lambda(1-\lambda)
(x^{(2)T}Mx^{(1)} + x^{(1)T}Mx^{(2)} - f(x^{(1)}) - f(x^{(2)}))
$$

And I need to proof that this is indeed $\ge$ than $\lambda f(x^{(1)}) + (1-\lambda)f(x^{(2)})$ however I can't see that it is trivial.

As an alternative, I have done the algebra a little differently, and ended up with the inequality:

$$
\lambda(1-\lambda)(f(x^{(1)}) + f(x^{(2)}) - x^{(2)T}Mx^{(1)} - x^{(1)T}Mx^{(2)}) \ge 0
$$

Which I am not entirely sure it is true.

If you guys need more specification, I will go into more detail. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is $M$ a SPD matrix?

Comment: Convexity of $f$ is equivalent to positive semidefinitness of $M$.

Comment: @CheungSW. Yes, it actually is PD (Positive Definite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean $M$ is a SPD matrix here. If $M = -1$ and $f(x) = -x^2$, we cannot obtain the conclusion.

If $M$ is a SPD matrix, we can write its Cholesky factorization $M=LL^T$.

$f(x) = x^TMx = ||L^Tx||_2^2$ is actually a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and therefore is a convex function.

More directly, we have $\nabla f = 2Mx$ and hence

$$(y - x)^T M (y - x) \geq 0$$
$$y^TMy \geq x^TMx + 2x^TM^T(y-x)$$
$$f(y) \geq f(x) + \nabla f^T(y-x)$$

for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, which is a N&S condition for a differentiable function to be convex.

Comment: Thank you!! Very elegant answer

Comment: You are welcome. :) Thanks for your appreciation.